# angular-cli : running test suites running all suites rather one pointed suites

Tags: angular, protractor, angular-cli, angular-test

I am in a situation where I need to run different set test cases for different purpose. Like for smoke test I am running 2 test cases and for regression I need to run 30 test cases. I have `suites` defined in my `protractor.conf.js` and I am calling the suites from `ng` command

```
exports.config = {
  suites: {
    smoke: [
      './e2e/**/smoke/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
    ],
    regression: [
      './e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
    ]
  },
  ...
}
```

In angular cli `ng e2e -- --suite=smoke` suppose to run only one test case but actually its running all the test cases in my project.

No idea why its running all the test case rather only one test case.

I have gone through [ng --suite issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/807), looks like its a real issue in angular cli.

Comment: Are you certain that the additional `--suite` argument is getting to protractor? What happens if you run protractor with the argument more directly?

Comment: Protractor is getting the suite name. I confirmed by putting a breakpoint while running the protractor command.

Comment: I think its a problem with angular cli `ng` command. it unable to take protractor parameters

Comment: That's not necessarily a problem with it. It's not something it claims to do!

Comment: `--` is a red flag. It specifies the end of named options, all the following arguments are considered positional ones. Try removing it.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev tried that too

Comment: @jonrsharpe, there are few issue related this in the cli git repo  - https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/807   ,   https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/3551

Comment: And that issue says it **isn't** currently supported functionality. Why have you commented on it saying something that isn't provided functionality doesn't work; why would it? The docs don't say it does: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/e2e. Split it into two configs if you want to use built-in functionality.

Comment: And either way, this isn't a question SO can answer: if they did claim that worked it would be a bug report; as it is it's a feature request or a pull request.

Comment: Issue link
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/807
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/3551